# CEF4Delphi certificate selection window

Tags: delphi, x509certificate, cef4delphi

I'm using CEF4Delphi to browse a site, this site asks for a certificate installed on windows, the documentation says I need to select this certificate in the "SelectClientCertificate" event in a callback function passing the index, my question is how to show this certificate window to select one of them

```
procedure TFPrin.WebBCSelectClientCertificate(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; isProxy: Boolean; const host: ustring;
  port: Integer; certificatesCount: NativeUInt;
  const certificates: TCefX509CertificateArray;
  const callback: ICefSelectClientCertificateCallback; var aResult: Boolean);
begin
  aresult:=true;
  //show certificate window here?
  callback.Select(certificates[Certindex]);
end;
```

would it be the same window when accessing by firefox or chrome?

[image]

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Use [`.ShowModal()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ShowModal) of your favorite Form - that's the core concept of modal windows.

Comment: I need to list the certificates installed on windows for the user to select...

Comment: There are various controls with which you can achieve that: `TRadioGroup`, `TListView`, `TListBox`... just like you'll most likely use `TButton` for each button. Design a Form with a few controls, fill that one control with content, then display the Form. What's your actual question?

Comment: @AmigoJack I want to show all certificates contained in "`const certificates: TCefX509CertificateArray;`" for the user to select one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand where the big deal is: you just display either a Form that you've designed just like any other Form, or you temporarily create one on the fly, just to destroy it again. **How** you plan to display each certificate (level of detail, fancyness, colors...) is up to you and (of course) works better with a Form already designed.

This is an example with a Form created on the fly:

```pas
procedure TFPrin.Chromium1SelectClientCertificate
( Sender: TObject
; const browser: ICefBrowser
; isProxy: Boolean
; const host: uCEFTypes.ustring
; port: Integer
; certificatesCount: Cardinal
; const certificates: TCefX509CertificateArray
; const callback: ICefSelectClientCertificateCallback
; var aResult: Boolean
);
var
  iCert: Integer;  // Which certificate we're just analyzing
  sLine: String;   // Information about the current certificate
  frm: TForm;      // Displayed (temporary) modal window
  lbx: TListBox;   // All certificates to choose from
  pan: TPanel;     // For the buttons

  // Converting a certificate time
  function _TimeToStr( vTime: TCefTime ): String;
  begin
    result:= IntToStr( vTime.year )+ '-'
           + IntToStr( vTime.month )+ '-'
           + IntToStr( vTime.day_of_month );
  end;

begin
  // Create temporary form...
  frm:= TForm.Create( Application );
  with frm do begin
    try
      BorderStyle:= bsSizeable;

      // ...along with its temporary controls:

      // Bottom panel, which will contain both buttons
      pan:= TPanel.Create( frm );
      with pan do begin
        Parent:= frm;
        Align:= alBottom;
        Height:= 30;
      end;

      // Buttons that automatically set the form's modal result
      with TButton.Create( frm ) do begin
        Parent:= pan;
        Caption:= '&Ok';
        ModalResult:= ID_OK;
        Default:= True;  // We can press ENTER anywhere to trigger this button
        Top:= 3;
        Left:= 10;
      end;
      with TButton.Create( frm ) do begin
        Parent:= pan;
        Caption:= '&Cancel';
        ModalResult:= ID_CANCEL;
        Cancel:= True;  // We can press ESC anywhere to trigger this button
        Top:= 3;
        Left:= 100;
      end;

      // A list displaying one certificate per line to choose from
      lbx:= TListBox.Create( frm );
      with lbx do begin
        Parent:= frm;
        Align:= alClient;
      end;


      // Now going thru all certificate details and adding each resulting text line to the listbox
      for iCert:= Low( certificates ) to High( certificates ) do begin
        sLine:= 'Subject: '+   certificates[iCert].GetSubject().GetDisplayName()+  '. '
              + 'Issuer: '+    certificates[iCert].GetIssuer().GetDisplayName()+   '. '
              + 'Valid from '+ _TimeToStr( certificates[iCert].GetValidStart() )+  ' to '
              +                _TimeToStr( certificates[iCert].GetValidExpiry() )+ '.';
        lbx.Items.Add( sLine );
      end;
      if lbx.Count> 0 then lbx.ItemIndex:= 0;  // Pre-select first certificate


      // Display the form and check if the "Ok" button has been pressed and a line is selected.
      // If yes, actually choose a certificate.
      aResult:= (ShowModal()= ID_OK) and (lbx.ItemIndex<> -1);
      if aResult then callback.Select( certificates[lbx.ItemIndex] );
    finally
      // Free temporary form and all its controls
      frm.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And this is an example for calling one of your existing Forms:

```pas
uses
  frmOther;

procedure TFPrin.Chromium1SelectClientCertificate
...
var
  iCert: Integer;  // Which certificate we're just analyzing
  sLine: String;   // Information about the current certificate

  // Converting a certificate time
  function _TimeToStr( vTime: TCefTime ): String;
  begin
    result:= IntToStr( vTime.year )+ '-'
           + IntToStr( vTime.month )+ '-'
           + IntToStr( vTime.day_of_month );
  end;

begin
  // Remove any existing entries in TFOther
  FOther.lbxCert.Clear();

  // Now going thru all certificate details and adding each resulting text line to the listbox
  for iCert:= Low( certificates ) to High( certificates ) do begin
    sLine:= 'Subject: '+   certificates[iCert].GetSubject().GetDisplayName()+  '. '
          + 'Issuer: '+    certificates[iCert].GetIssuer().GetDisplayName()+   '. '
          + 'Valid from '+ _TimeToStr( certificates[iCert].GetValidStart() )+  ' to '
          +                _TimeToStr( certificates[iCert].GetValidExpiry() )+ '.';
    FOther.lbxCert.Items.Add( sLine );
  end;
  if FOther.lbxCert.Count> 0 then FOther.lbxCert.ItemIndex:= 0;  // Pre-select first certificate


  // Display the form and check if the "Ok" button has been pressed and a line is selected.
  // If yes, actually choose a certificate.
  aResult:= (FOther.ShowModal()= ID_OK) and (FOther.lbxCert.ItemIndex<> -1);
  if aResult then callback.Select( certificates[FOther.lbxCert.ItemIndex] );
end;
```

Using the types/interfaces can't be more straight - just look at their definitions:

- `TCefX509CertificateArray` is defined in **uCEFInterfaces.pas**,
- along with everything that also comes with that: `ICefX509Certificate` and `ICefX509CertPrincipal`.
- `TCefTime` is defined in **uCEFTypes.pas**.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted!